# How to connect method from another class to actionListener?

Tags: java

I'm trying to finish my project about searching graphs, where one of the functions is input (vertex and edges) from user.

I already have a method for this in another class, but now I need to put it into GUI.

I've already tried many of tutorials, but nothing worked. Can somebody help me, how to put the method `getInputFromCommand` to gui?

I've already tried to copy the method into the GUI, but there was problem with the "return g" because of the void result type, I've tried just to call the method, (I know.. stupid) but it didn't work either.

```
package Process;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindIslands {



String message = "";
int V;
LinkedList<Integer>[] adjListArray;
static LinkedList<String> nodeList = new LinkedList<String>();

// constructor
FindIslands(int V) {
    this.V = V;

    adjListArray = new LinkedList[V];

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        adjListArray[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
}

void addEdge(int src, int dest) {

    adjListArray[src].add(dest);
    adjListArray[dest].add(src);
}

void DFSUtil(int v, boolean[] visited) {
    visited[v] = true;
    message += getValue(v) + " ";
    //   System.out.print(getValue(v) + " ");

    for (int x : adjListArray[v]) {
        if (!visited[x]) {
            DFSUtil(x, visited);
        }
    }

}

void connectedComponents() {

    boolean[] visited = new boolean[V];
    int count = 0;
    message = "";
    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v) {
        if (!visited[v]) {

            DFSUtil(v, visited);
            message += "\n";
            //     System.out.println();
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("" + count);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Vypis ostrovu: ");
    String W[] = message.split("\n");
    Arrays.sort(W, new java.util.Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            // TODO: Argument validation (nullity, length)
            return s1.length() - s2.length();// comparison
        }
    });
    for (String string : W) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    FindIslands g = null; //
    String csvFile = "nodefile.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    int emptyLine = 0;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals("")) {
                emptyLine = 1;
                //    System.out.println("found blank line");
            }
            if (emptyLine == 0) {
                // System.out.println(line);
                nodeList.add(line);
            } else if (line.isEmpty()) {
                g = new FindIslands(nodeList.size());
            } else {
                String[] temp = line.split(",");
                g.addEdge(getIndex(temp[0]), getIndex(temp[1]));
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Soubor nenalezen, zadejte data v danem formatu");
        g = getInputFromCommand();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Pocet ostrovu");
    if (g != null) {
        g.connectedComponents();


    }
}


public static int getIndex(String str) {
    return nodeList.indexOf(str);
}

public static String getValue(int index) {
    return nodeList.get(index);
}

public static FindIslands getInputFromCommand() {


    FindIslands g = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    int emptyLine = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    line = scanner.nextLine();
    while (!line.equals("")) {
        if (line.equals("--gui")) {
            Guicko gui = new Guicko();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        } else
            nodeList.add(line);
            line = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        g = new FindIslands(nodeList.size());
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        while (!line.equals("")) {
            String[] temp = line.split(",");
            if (temp.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("spatny format zadanych dat, prosim zkuste znovu");
            } else {
                g.addEdge(getIndex(temp[0]), getIndex(temp[1]));
            }

            line = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        return g;
    }

}
```

Where important is the last method "getInputFromCommand()"

and... gui

```
package Process;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Guicko extends JFrame {
private JButton štartButton;
private JPanel panel;
private JTextField textField2;
private JTextArea textArea1;


public Guicko() {
    add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Zadej hodnoty");

    setSize(500, 400);

    textField2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            FindIslands.getInputFromCommand();
        }
    });

    štartButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String str = "asd";
            FindIslands g = null;
            g.connectedComponents();
            textArea1.setText(str);
        }
    });



}



public static void main (String args[]){
    Guicko gui = new Guicko();
    gui.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: `FindIslands g = null;
            g.connectedComponents();` isn't null?

Comment: There is a design pattern, called `Observer`. That is what you need. Search and look for example btw before that you need to instantiate your class properly.

Comment: @KhanSaab g is filled later, so g.connectedComponents() is not null. That method is working, I  just have a problem to connect it with gui. I'll check that Observer pattern. Thank you :)

Comment: that will throw a `null pointer exception`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many correct ways this code can be fixed, but in IMHO, your Guicko class needs to have a FindIslands class member, and I think you need to move some stuff from `FindIslands.main()` into `Guicko.main()` or some other method.

Then your "Action Listener" inner classes' actionPerformed methods just delegate to the methods in the FindIslands member instance, like this

```
....
private FindIslands fi;

public Guicko() {
    ....
    textField2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fi = FindIslands.getInputFromCommand();
        }
    });

    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String comps = fi.connectedComponents();// method needs to return a string
            textArea1.setText(comps);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of seperating `GUI` from `domain` is to make changes easily. `GUI` has knowledge of the `domain` but `domain` has no knowledge about the `GUI`. We can use an interface to seperate them, in that case, `Domain` says , i don't care who implements this interface but whoever implements this interface will get response and can work with me.

So , If we create a new `GUI`, we can let it implements that interface and the same `domain` will work with that `GUI`.

There are many mistakes but in order to make it work and to show you an example i did few changes.

```
public class Guicko extends JFrame implements PropertyChangeListener{
   private JButton štartButton;
   private JPanel panel;
   private JTextField textField2;
   private JTextArea textArea1;
   private FindIslands land;

   private JTextField textField;
   private JButton button;



public Guicko() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    super.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout());

    //For each gui, there should be one land.
    this.setLand(new FindIslands(100));


    //Subscribe to the domain so that you can get update if something change in domain.
    this.getLand().subscribe(this);


    //Dummy buttons are fields(need too initiate first)
    textField2 = new JTextField("",30);
    štartButton = new JButton();
    textField = new JTextField("",30);
    button = new JButton();
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
    button.setText("Get input from Domain");
    štartButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
    textField.setEditable(false);
    štartButton.setText("Start");
    panel.add(textField2);
    panel.add(štartButton);
    panel.add(textField);
    panel.add(button);



    add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Zadej hodnoty");

    setSize(500, 400);

    //When you type something in , then this function will send it to domain(i mean to function : getInputFromCommand();).
    this.addListerToField(štartButton,this.getLand(),textField2);


    //Now the second case, suppose you press a button and want something to show up in textfield. In that case , this function will do work.
    this.addListerToSecondField(button,this.getLand(),textField);

}



//Here i can catch the events from the domain.
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
    if(e.getPropertyName().equals("String changed")) {
        this.getTextField().setText((String) e.getNewValue());
    }
}





private void addListerToSecondField(JButton button, FindIslands land, JTextField field) {
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            land.requireArgumentsForField();
        }

    });
}





private void addListerToField(JButton štartButton, FindIslands land, JTextField field) {
    štartButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                land.getInputFromCommand(field.getText());
            }
        });
}



public static void main (String args[]){
    Guicko gui = new Guicko();
    gui.setVisible(true);
 }



public FindIslands getLand() {
    return land;
}



public void setLand(FindIslands land) {
    this.land = land;
}






public JTextField getTextField() {
    return textField;
}





public void setTextField(JTextField textField) {
    this.textField = textField;
}





public JButton getButton() {
    return button;
}





public void setButton(JButton button) {
    this.button = button;
}
```

Here is the second class. Run it and try to get feeling for it how it works.

```
 public class FindIslands {




String message = "";
int V;
LinkedList<Integer>[] adjListArray;
static LinkedList<String> nodeList = new LinkedList<String>();

// constructor
FindIslands(int V) {
    this.V = V;
    //initialize the list
    this.setListeners(new ArrayList<>());

    adjListArray = new LinkedList[V];

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        adjListArray[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
}

void addEdge(int src, int dest) {

    adjListArray[src].add(dest);
    adjListArray[dest].add(src);
}

void DFSUtil(int v, boolean[] visited) {
    visited[v] = true;
    message += getValue(v) + " ";
    //   System.out.print(getValue(v) + " ");

    for (int x : adjListArray[v]) {
        if (!visited[x]) {
            DFSUtil(x, visited);
        }
    }

}

void connectedComponents() {

    boolean[] visited = new boolean[V];
    int count = 0;
    message = "";
    for (int v = 0; v < V; ++v) {
        if (!visited[v]) {

            DFSUtil(v, visited);
            message += "\n";
            //     System.out.println();
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("" + count);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Vypis ostrovu: ");
    String W[] = message.split("\n");
    Arrays.sort(W, new java.util.Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            // TODO: Argument validation (nullity, length)
            return s1.length() - s2.length();// comparison
        }
    });
    for (String string : W) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}

//You need only one main class, not two.----------------------------
/**
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FindIslands g = null; //
    String csvFile = "nodefile.txt";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    int emptyLine = 0;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.equals("")) {
                emptyLine = 1;
                //    System.out.println("found blank line");
            }
            if (emptyLine == 0) {
                // System.out.println(line);
                nodeList.add(line);
            } else if (line.isEmpty()) {
                g = new FindIslands(nodeList.size());
            } else {
                String[] temp = line.split(",");
                g.addEdge(getIndex(temp[0]), getIndex(temp[1]));
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Soubor nenalezen, zadejte data v danem formatu");
        g = getInputFromCommand();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Pocet ostrovu");
    if (g != null) {
        g.connectedComponents();


    }
}
**/

public static int getIndex(String str) {
    return nodeList.indexOf(str);
}

public static String getValue(int index) {
    return nodeList.get(index);
}


//Static cases are to be avoided.This is the property of object not class.
public void getInputFromCommand(String string) {

    //Here you will recieve a string from the GUI and will be printed in command prompt.You can do whatever you want to do with it.
    System.out.println("Recieve string is " + string);



    //No idea what you are trying to do.
   /** FindIslands g = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    int emptyLine = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    line = scanner.nextLine();
    while (!line.equals("")) {
        if (line.equals("--gui")) {
            Guicko gui = new Guicko();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        } else
            nodeList.add(line);
            line = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        g = new FindIslands(nodeList.size());
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        while (!line.equals("")) {
            String[] temp = line.split(",");
            if (temp.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("spatny format zadanych dat, prosim zkuste znovu");
            } else {
                g.addEdge(getIndex(temp[0]), getIndex(temp[1]));
            }

            line = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        return line;**/
    }

//This function is triggered with second button and you can send data to gui as shown below.
public void requireArgumentsForField() {
    //Suppose i want to send following string.
    String name = "I don't know";
    this.getListeners().stream().forEach(e -> {
        //  I will catch this in view.
        e.propertyChange(new PropertyChangeEvent(this, "String changed", null, name));
    });
}

private ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener> listeners;


//Let the objects subscibe. You need this to publish the changes in domain.
public void subscribe(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    this.getListeners().add(listener);
}



public ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener> getListeners() {
    return listeners;
}

public void setListeners(ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener> listeners) {
    this.listeners = listeners;
}
```